How to add some spacing on the left and right or X axis marks in LineMark
I have a LineMark where my X axis marks are too close to the edges and a bit hard to read:
Chart {
  ForEach(numberWorkouts) { numberworkouts in
    if dateState == .weeks {
      LineMark(
        x: .value("Date", numberworkouts.date, unit: .day),
        y: .value("Total", numberworkouts.numberOfWorkouts)
      )
      .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
      .symbol {
        Circle()
          .fill(.blue)
          .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
      }
    } else {
      LineMark(
        x: .value("Date", numberworkouts.date, unit: .month),
        y: .value("Total", numberworkouts.numberOfWorkouts)
      )
      .symbol {
        Circle()
          .fill(.blue)
          .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
      }
    }
  }
}
.chartYAxis {
  AxisMarks(position: .leading)
}
.chartYAxisLabel(position: .leading, alignment: .center) {
}
.chartYAxis {
  AxisMarks(stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0))
}
.chartXAxis {
  if dateState == .weeks {
    AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, values: .stride(by: .day, count: 7)) {
      AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.twoDigits).day())
    }
  } else {
    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) {
      AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated), centered: true)
    }
  }
}
//.chartForegroundStyleScale(dataType == .MaxWeight ? ["Max Weight": Color.blue] : ["One Rep Max": Color.blue] )
.chartForegroundStyleScale(["No. of Workouts": Color.blue])
.chartLegend(.visible)
.aspectRatio(1.7, contentMode: .fit)
//.padding()


how do I push the 17/7 and 07/08 a bit inside, I have tried applying padding to the chart but that applies padding to the outside of the LineMark and the LineMark wont accept padding as a modifier

Try adding an anchor parameter to AxisValueLabel

And perhaps add AxisGridLine() to further clarify the week with a centered anchor.

You can add an anchor parameter to AxisValueLabel.
If you want to use different anchors depending on whether it is the first, intermediate or last value, you can use the AxisValues initializer that supports a closure for defining the axis marker content: init(preset:position:values:content:).
The content closure receives an AxisValue as parameter and this includes the properties index and count:
AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day, count: 7)) { value in
    AxisValueLabel(
        format: .dateTime.month(.twoDigits).day(),
        anchor: value.index == 0
            ? .topLeading
            : value.index == value.count - 1 ? .topTrailing : .top
    )
}


For more on formatting possibilities, see Customizing axes in Swift Charts.

This worked but that documentation doesn't seem to contain what you did can you explain this part? value.index == value.count - 1 ? .topTrailing : .top

Correction: when you try to use a custom UnitPoint it gives you an error in the console. So the anchor needs to be one of the standard UnitPoint constants.

@johnsmith Not sure if I answered your question with my previous reply, here's another try. Each axis value has an index (ref. the documentation) which is 0-based. So the first value will have an index of 0 and the last value will have an index of (count - 1). The line you're asking about is the "else" part of a ternary operator. This contains another ternary operator, which is checking for the last value. When identified, the last value uses .topTrailing alignment, all other values use .top alignment.
